# How to make a circular waveform using FFMPEG

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, waveform, visualizer

I am trying to generate a waveform using ffmpeg.

I have successfully made a horizontal waveform thanks to pretty good docs(https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Waveform).

However I'm struggling to create circular waveform.

I want something like this

[image]

Comment: Not sure if you mean a single, static waveform image generated at the end of a recording or something jumping around dynamically as it is played back. If you mean the former, you might be able to adapt a linear waveform with **ImageMagick** polar distortion tool https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#polar

Comment: @MarkSetchell I don't want static image, I want dynamic waveform that will play along audio.